# Size of collection view cell changes when I scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

I have a collection view (horizontal) nested inside my tableview (vertical). When I scroll through my `UITableView` the size of the cell increases and scrolls a bit to the left. I have unchecked estimated size for collection view.

This is how I set up the layout for collection view:

```swift
func setLayout() {
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = .zero
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.lifeStyleCollectionView.frame.width / 2 - 10, height: self.lifeStyleCollectionView.frame.width / 2 - 10)
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 12
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    self.lifeStyleCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: is your tableView has automatic row height or fixed row height??

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology tableview has fixed row height

Comment: @lyncx: Please add bit more code to work with, like tableView delegates collection view delegates specially anything to do with size of cell

Comment: where did you call `setLayout()`?